# How to combine 2 CSV files into one by joining columns

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

file1.csv

```
name,surname
tom,brown
aaron,brown
jon,doe
```

file2.csv

```
age
22
24
26
```

I want an output to be a file result.csv with the following content:

```
name,surname,age
tom,brown,22
aaron,brown,24
jon,doe,26
```

Comment: what about a `?cbind` ?

Comment: Specifically, `write.csv(cbind(read.csv("file1.csv"), read.csv("file2.csv")), "result.csv")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do cbind, as suggested in the comments.

```
df1= read.csv("file1.csv", header=T)
df2= read.csv("file2.csv", header=T)
df= cbind(df1, df2)
write.csv(df, "file.csv)
```

They just have to be the same length. Add NAs if you need to.